# All scripts AND libraries in ONE js script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I am in the process of building my first Javascript 'framework' or 'bootstrap' which will be implemented in combination with a single pre-processed CSS file. I am gathering my favorite content slider, smooth scroller, content slideshow, parallax elements & bg-img, sticky elements, among a few more cutting edge navigational & UI based scripts (cross-browser/platform/device/viewport compatibility and performance). My problem is when constructing my demo page with all combined elements in place loaded and active on the page... well many seeem to require a different version of Jquery to be called in order to function properly. I have managed to get them to work properly while testing by carefully reordering the jquery librarys as they are called in the  of the page. Now here is my (2) part question:

1. How do I get all my JQuery to work properly without loading multiple versions of it (one for each script almost)
2. I have a sample in my portfolio which I would love to use as the example. http://www.nicholasabrams.com/  (non mobile device version). In the src for that URL you will see only (1) js and (1) css - *including* the jquery libraries which are ALSO included in the single .js in the begining of the file. Please don't flame me, as I am asking for help. The link above works fine now (with apple as a slight exception)... but I am just trying to eliminate any bad practices I have as I have just started as a web developer at my first large company. Thanks!!

PS: Would post a snippet but its quite a large js file as you would imagine but if you will, please inspect my src and let me know what you think because my sites first load decreased from 22 seconds to 4-7 seconds after doing the above I wish I could just include the latest version of JQuery!)

Comment: I can tell you that multiple versions of jQuery on the same page is going to cause conflicts for sure.

Comment: but it has not, check the link, no console errors related to anything of the sort

Comment: You have a [2.4mb image](http://www.nicholasabrams.com/bg-cb-HiRes.jpg) and a huge modal dialog that doesn't go away until *everything* has loaded. No user is going to wait 30 seconds for your website to load. JavaScript is the least of your concerns.

Comment: yes I know its not perfect and I didnt realize the size of the BG, but in a day in age with 50Mb connectivity becoming common... can we leave this about the JQuery... this is a common issue that has not been really truly covered. What do you do when you have code from multiple sources that is written for multiple versions of JQuery?

Comment: @user2691203: I have a decent connection and if it takes me 30 seconds to download it, someone with DSL is going to be waiting for more than a minute. Your site should load in a few seconds.

Comment: @user2691203: As for your question, I use the latest version of jQuery and modify the scripts that I use (if any) to work with it, so that's not really an issue for me. Just use the latest version and see what errors you get. There aren't many changes between versions.

Comment: ok well I will turn that bg image to a jpg and that takes 2MB off of the load... which would account for the excess load time completely. Come on guys I appreciate your help but who knows the real answer? What is the harm in loading all jquery libs in the script before loading your custom scripts with the noconflict var between all of them? I am willing to post results if anyone thinks this could be an easy way to place jquery scripts throughout site with just one single js include? If the page loads in around 5-10 secs. Wouldn't this eliminate alot of heartache? JQuery Libs arent THAT big.

Comment: @user2691203: 5-10 seconds is still too long. This page loads in less than a second and is only 160kb. As for jQuery, sure, it isn't that big, but you can say that about everything on your site. 400kb isn't *that* big, but when you have six of those libraries loaded along with images, your site becomes incredibly bloated. Keep it slim.

Comment: The animation on your background makes me physically ill. That's not a joke - I had to close the tab because I was feeling nauseated. If that's your goal, you did admirably, but it's likely going to discourage views.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly you are loading more than one jQuery library to the page (in different order)? That's a mistake - you shouldn't do that.

What you should do is make sure that the plugins you work with are compatible with the library you are working with. If they're not - wither find other plugins or fix the ones you have to support the jQuery language you are using.

Comment: Thank you, I have only basic concept of Javascript down... how hard is it to convert a typical jquery script into one that say works in (JQuery 2 or any recent build). Also isnt this what the NoConflict var is passed for?

Comment: It depends on the code. Each code is on it's own. What happens is that jQuery functions might change from version to version or even removed (since they are no longer needed or there's something new to replace them). What I would start with is searching for the plugin on google and see if the developer released a newer version that is compatible with newer jQuery languages.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 2 megabyte hi-res background image, that is insane! I would scrap that and the swirl image, while it may look cool to you, it is distracting and may actually make people want to avoid your website. It makes it difficult to concentrate on the text in the middle of your screen. You don't want people to remember the swirling image, but rather your portfolio, right?

You also have 404's on the following:

1. http://www.nicholasabrams.com/ScrollSpy_files/result-light.css
2. http://www.nicholasabrams.com/example-images/testing_station.png

404's are bad for several reasons, they are a wasted resource as they slow the loading of your page, because it attempts to find something and does not find it, and, finally, they have a negative impact on your SEO, specifically Google PageRank docks you for any 404's.

Find a way to work with one version of jQuery, it will eventually bite you to have multiple versions of the library and it is a bandwidth killer to have your users load up a bunch of libraries, even if they are CDN'd.

Comment: Ok, I do realize that its bad and thank you for your response... however I dont wish to seem hardheaded, but I like to understand why not instead of just know that it should be. Im looking for a more technical answer if at all possible. Why does no conflict exist? Why doesnt jquery simply build upon the library instead of making similar but different sources that are incompatible with one another . Almost all JQuery scripts call a different library, which is well.. dumb for being based on a language known for compatibility.

Comment: The point of JQuery is for people who either cannot or care not to write javascript code. I guess I'm out numbered...

Comment: @user2691203: That's not true at all. jQuery is a JavaScript library that handles browser inconsistencies and provides a simplified interface for interacting with the DOM and sending AJAX requests. It's definitely *not* "for people who either cannot or care not to write javascript code". Learn JavaScript before touching jQuery and things like this won't be an issue, as you'll have the tools to just fix those scripts (or write your own).

Comment: @user2691203 - that is a ludicrous statement, jQuery is an abstraction of JavaScript, because it is written in JavaScript.

Comment: Write less. Do more. This is slogan on their front page and the first words in the description of the technology in there meta description (see: jquery.com...), so excuse me for thinking of JQuery as an easier form of Javascript! I am trying to learn Javascript and Jquery and this is part of the process. Dont forget where you came from, being humble is a sign of wisdom and a real expert of any field.

Comment: @user2691203 - I apologize, I took your statement of "jQuery is for people who either cannot or care not to write JavaScript code" as condescending. My apologies, good luck with your jQuery adventure.